# Value of type 'FormBaseCell' has no member

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new in xcode programming and came across this error. I'm not sure what the new updated xcode wants me to do here since it worked before I upgraded.

The error:

> Value of type 'FormBaseCell' has no member.

My code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let rowDescriptor = formRowDescriptorAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    let formBaseCellClass = formBaseCellClassFromRowDescriptor(rowDescriptor)

    let reuseIdentifier = NSStringFromClass(formBaseCellClass)

    var cell: FormBaseCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as? FormBaseCell
    if cell == nil {

        cell = formBaseCellClass.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        cell?.tableViewController = self // <--error 
        cell?.configure()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got this code from. I have never seen anyone go through all these steps to get a cell.  You should just be able to do this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Set up your table and prototype cell on storyboard
    let reuseIdentifier = "MyCell"

    var cell: FormBaseCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as? FormBaseCell
    if let cell = cell {
        cell.textLabel.text = "something"
    }
    else {
        cell = FormBaseCell()
    }
    return cell
}
```